# Sorting to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a problem when trying to sort an array alphabetically into another array.

This is what the original array looks like:

```
var palavras = new Array(5);

palavras[0] = "Português";
palavras[1] = "Inglês";
palavras[2] = "Programação C";
palavras[3] = "Programação JS";
palavras[4] = "Educação Física";
```

I need to sort this array alphabetically into another array but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is the expected output of the other array:

```
arraySorted[0] = "Educação Física";
arraySorted[1] = "Inglês";
arraySorted[2] = "Português";
arraySorted[3] = "Programação C";
arraySorted[4] = "Programação JS";
```

I'm new to StackOverflow so I don't know how to use the tools to make it more understandable but I hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: use arrayName.sort() function.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?  You can [sort an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), but if you don't want the *original* array sorted then you would need to copy the elements into a new array.

Comment: Create a shallow copy of the array `const arraySorted = Array.from(palavras)`, then sort the copy `arraySorted.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, You want to keep original array unsorted.
So you have to create new array from original one:

```
arraySorted = palavras.slice()
```

and then you can sort:

```
arraySorted.sort()
```

Array.slice() returns new array, without any param it returns array with the same values and length.
Array.sort() changes array original array so without slice you would have both arrays changed